# Multiply in SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query with no result which I don't understand:

```
(
  select checkinkilometer 
  from rentobjtransact 
  where rentcontract.rentcontractid = rentobjtransact.rentcontractid 
  and RentObjTransact.isActive = 1
) *
(
  case when RentObj.isAlienRentObj = 0 
    then TO_CHAR(car.CO2Emission, '999999') 
    else rentobj.ClassificDescr3
  end
) - 
(
  select checkoutkilometer 
  from rentobjtransact 
  where rentcontract.rentcontractid = rentobjtransact.rentcontractid 
  and RentObjTransact.isActive = 1
) *
(
  case when RentObj.isAlienRentObj = 0
    then TO_CHAR(car.CO2Emission, '999999') 
    else rentobj.ClassificDescr3 
  end
) as "CO2 verbruik"
```

When I take a part of the code I get a result which is right:

```
(
  select checkinkilometer 
  from rentobjtransact 
  where rentcontract.rentcontractid = rentobjtransact.rentcontractid 
  and RentObjTransact.isActive = 1
) -
(
  select checkoutkilometer 
  from rentobjtransact 
  where rentcontract.rentcontractid = rentobjtransact.rentcontractid 
  and RentObjTransact.isActive = 1
) as "km"
```

and also,

```
(
  case when RentObj.isAlienRentObj = 0 
    then TO_CHAR(car.CO2Emission, '999999') 
    else rentobj.ClassificDescr3 
  end
) as "CO2"
```

is correct. But when I want to combine the code I get no result. Please give me a hint?

Comment: Format code as code please.

Comment: So these are subqueries in your query's select clause? And "no result" means the computed value is null?

Comment: It seems strange that you want to multiply with a string: `then TO_CHAR(car.CO2Emission, '999999') else rentobj.ClassificDescr3`.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, that's right "No result" means Null. Yes I want to Multiply the result of KM and CO2.